# PrintWriter not creating output with supposed number of rows

Tags: java, csv

I have a java program that is supposed to output data, take in data again, read and then output with a few extra columns of result. (So two outputs in total) To test my program I just tried to read and print out the exact same csv to see if it works. However, my first output returns 786718 rows of data, which is complete and correct, but when it gets read again to output the second time, the data is cut at row 786595 and even that row is missing some column data. The file size is also 74868KB vs 74072KB of data. Is this because of the lack of memory from my java program or excel/the .csv file's problem?

```
    PrintWriter writer = null;
    try {
        writer = new PrintWriter(saveFileName + " updated.csv", "UTF-8");

        for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList> entry : readOutputCSV(saveFileName).entrySet()) {
            FindOutput.find(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), checkInMRTWriter);
        }
    } finally {
        if (writer != null) {
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Without your code, no way to tell what is going wrong.

Comment: You aren't writing anything to the `writer`. This code will produce zero-length files. NB `flush()` before `close()` is redundant.

Comment: FindOutput.find is another method that writes the lines to the writer! it is working, only problem is that the csv file is not complete!

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason is you are not flushing nor closing the PrintWriter.

From the Java source

```
public PrintWriter(OutputStream out) {
    this(out, false);
}

public PrintWriter(OutputStream out, boolean autoFlush) {
    this(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out)), autoFlush);
```

You can see that PrintWriter is buffered by default.

The default buffer size is 8 KiB so if you leave this data in the buffer and don't write it out you can lose up to the last 8 KiB of your data.

Comment: Hi Peter, I've updated my question with my codes, but I have flushed and closed my printer, despite so I still have the same problem! :-(

Comment: @user3763216 You close `writer` but you don't actually seem to use it. Is code missing?

Answer (score 0):

Some things might influence here:

- input/output encoding
- line separators (you might be reading a file with '\r\n' and writing '\n' back
- CSV escape - values might be escaped or not depending on how you are handling the special cases (values with newlines, comma, or quote). You might be reading valid CSV with a parser but printing out unescaped (and broken) CSV.
- whitespaces. Some libraries clear the whitespace when parsing automatically.

The best way to verify is to use a CSV parsing library, such as [univocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) and use it to read/write your data with a fixed format configuration. Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).